# Find patches of given size in circular shape from numpy array having no zero values

Tags: python, numpy

Let say, I have a grayscale image that has some black pixels as shown below:

[image]

In this image, I am trying to find out patches having no zero values. For simplicity, let's assume that overlapping patches are allowed. The challenge is that these patches aren't rectangular but circular in shape. Please see an example below:

[image]

Please note that there are many such patches possible in the image. However, for illustration purposes, I have just manually drawn a few.

It is possible to find such patches using for nested `for` loop but this doesn't look the optimal way.

```
# find one circular patch
for y in range(-radius, radius):
    for x in range(-radius, radius):
        if x**2 + y**2 < radius**2:
            # this pixel in inside the circular patch
            patch_x, patch_y = img_x + x,  img_y + y
```

I am trying to use convolution operation but no luck so far

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

radius = 20

img = cv2.imread('img.png', cv2.CV_8UC1)

candidates = img != 0
patch_shape = (radius, radius)
out = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
    candidates,
    shape=(candidates.shape[0] - patch_shape[0] + 1, \
           candidates.shape[1] - patch_shape[1] + 1, \
           *patch_shape),
    strides=2*img.strides,
    writeable=False,
)

patches = np.argwhere(out.all(axis=(-2, -1)))
```

**My goal is to find all (if not at least a few say 10) patches of given size in circular shape from Numpy array having no zero values.**

Comment: "no luck so far" - what output do you get?

Comment: @Stuart: For example, the variable `patches` have all square patches, that have all non-zero values. Ideally, I need circular patches, luckily in this approach, I can consider all square patches. But this way, I am missing some circular patches. Basically not getting how to proceed next...

Answer (score 0):

I would go with convolution.

There is a nice trick to generate a circular kernel (mask)

```
def create_circular_kernel(radius):
    center = (radius, radius)
    h = 2*radius
    w = 2*radius

    Y, X = np.ogrid[:h, :w]
    dist_from_center = np.sqrt((X - center[0])**2 + (Y-center[1])**2)
    mask = dist_from_center <= radius
    return mask
```

And then circle centers can be found using convolution:
In your case, it should be equal to zero.

```
from scipy.signal import correlate2d

radius = 20
kernel = create_circular_kernel(radius)
convolved_image = correlate2d(candidates, kernel, 'same')
patch_centers = np.where(convolved_image==0, 1,0)
```

This gives image with values 1, where you can draw a circle containing no zero values.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I tried using it but the detected centers aren't aligned properly. Please [see screenshot of the output here](https://i.ibb.co/3vGvJpP/outout.png). Additionally, you can [check my code at Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/SW9PcthS).